# Variance of Least Squares Estimate

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, linear-algebra

Universally the literature seems to make a jump in the proof of variance of the least squares estimator and I'm hoping you can fill in the gaps for me.

In matrix form, the least squares estimate is:

$$
E[W_{ML}] = E[(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y]
= (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Xw
$$

This makes sense, the variance is then:

$$
Var[W_{ML}] = E[(W_{ML}-E[W_{ML}])(W_{ML}-E[W_{ML}])^{T}]
$$

$$
Var[W_{ML}] = E[W_{ML}W_{ML}^{T}-E[W_{ML}]W_{ML}^{T} - W_{ML}E[W_{ML}]^{T}+E[W_{ML}]E[W_{ML}]^{T}]
$$

The literature always states that this is equivalent to

$$
E[W_{ML}W_{ML}^{T}] - E[W_{ML}]E[W_{ML}]^{T}
$$

But I can't decompose the steps to see how this is the case, can someone help me fill in the gaps?

Thanks!

Comment: Expectation is linear operator just smear it across additions an subtractions. Expectations are constant that can simply be taken out of expectations. As far as i can see that is all you need to use, unless i misunderstand your question.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3540489/321264.

Comment: What is $E[E[W_{ML}]W_{ML}^T]$?  Once you figure that out, you will be almost all the way there.